# How to convert numpy array to Open3D Image in python?

Tags: numpy, opencv, ros, open3d

I use image_transport pkg in ROS to transport numpy arrays (from OpenCV) to a listener written in python.

Now I want to convert a numpy array (from OpenCV) to *Open3D Image* data structure. How can I write this conversion? Is there any method that Open3D already have to finish this job?

Comment: OpenCV in python uses **numpy arrays**. look for that.

Comment: what is your issue with this? http://www.open3d.org/docs/0.9.0/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html#from-numpy-to-open3d-image